# Is it ok to pass entity objects in post method requestbody?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, http-post

I have a Springboot Rest project. Suppose I have User class as entity. Is it ok to pass this entity object directly in the RequestBody of a POST method? My funcionality will work smoothly with this. My question is , whether it is a security flaw? If yes what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine and is an easy implementation but architecturally this isn't a good practice because this tightly coupling your rest implementation with your database design and exposing it to the consumer of the API.

You should have request/response objects coming into your api and going out of it decoupling it from the database and allowing you to perform validations and other business rules at a layer above data access. If you find you are having to write a lot of assignment code between the entity and dtos then you can use a tool like http://modelmapper.org/ or http://mapstruct.org/

Comment: That is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You should never exposed critical data to the users. That being said if you don't want to create a separate DTO for each entity, you could use `Jackson Annotations` like `@JsonIgnore` to define which of the entity's fields you would like to receive or display to the users (considering you have a **REST** application).

So, as long as you don't expose critical data, you can do it however you want, yet creating DTOs is consider a good practice.